# which should be ran first git submodule update or git submodule init?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am seeing here # https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/73
:

```
# run git submodule update and the && makes sure init is only ran if the first worked
git submodule update && git submodule init  
# https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/73
```

But I believe this is the right/safer/more standard way:

```
# - git submodule init initializes your local configuration file to track the submodules your repository uses, it just sets up the configuration so that you can use the git submodule update command to clone and update the submodules.
git submodule init
# - The --remote option tells Git to update the submodule to the commit specified in the upstream repository, rather than the commit specified in the main repository. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988223/why-do-i-need-to-add-the-remote-to-gits-submodule-when-i-specify-the-branch?noredirect=1&lq=1
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
# - for each submodule pull from the right branch according to .gitmodule file. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988223/why-do-i-need-to-add-the-remote-to-gits-submodule-when-i-specify-the-branch?noredirect=1&lq=1
git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git switch $(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch || echo master || echo main )'
# - check it's in specified branch. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998463/why-does-git-submodule-status-not-match-the-output-of-git-branch-of-my-submodule
git submodule status
```

am I right? I'd love to be corrected or know the good practices for this.

---

cross:

- ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/10tydp4/which_should_be_ran_first_git_submodule_update_or/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler instruction for the [`UCSD-PL/proverbot9001`](https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001) repository, which references *a lot* of submodules (cf. [its `.gitmodules`](https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/blob/master/.gitmodules) file), would be to just use the [`git clone --recurse-submodules` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt):

That would do everything: clone the parent repository, initialize all submodules and update them. All in one go.

As explained in "[What is the point of '`git submodule init`'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46582526/6309)", separating both steps (init and update) makes sense when you do *not* want *all* submodules (because it would take too much time/resource to clone them), and want only to work on a subset.

In that case, yes, init must comes *before* update.

This comes from [commit be4d2c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be4d2c83b68a96285cc05036add4d64d324e52d9), Git v1.5.6-rc0, May 2008

> ### `submodule update`: add convenience option `--init`

> When a submodule is not initialized and you do not want to change the
> defaults from `.gitmodules` anyway, you can now say
>
> ```
> $ git submodule update --init <name>
> ```
>
> When "`update`" is called without `--init` on an uninitialized submodule, a hint to use `--init` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, `init` should be run before `update`.

As noted in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-init--ltpathgt82308203), `init` will

> Initialize the submodules recorded in the index (which were added and committed elsewhere) by setting submodule.$name.url in .git/config. It uses the same setting from .gitmodules as a template.

In other words, `init` sets up the configuration which will be used by `update`. If you're not making any local modifications to that config then you can also just run `update --init`. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203)

> If the submodule is not yet initialized, and you just want to use the setting as stored in .gitmodules, you can automatically initialize the submodule with the --init option.