# Why is git asking me for a username and a password when I try to clone git submodules?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I ran (following the instructions from this repo https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/74):

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

but got these prompts for the terminal/git:

```
Cloning into '/Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001/coq-projects/VST/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs'...
Username for 'https://github.com': brando90
Password for 'https://brando90@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs.git/'
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs.git' into submodule path '/Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001/coq-projects/VST/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs' failed
Failed to clone 'coqdocjs'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001/coq-projects/VST/coq-ext-lib/templates'...
Username for 'https://github.com': 
Password for 'https://github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/templates.git/'
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/templates.git' into submodule path '/Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001/coq-projects/VST/coq-ext-lib/templates' failed
Failed to clone 'templates'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001/coq-projects/VST/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs'...
Username for 'https://github.com': 
Password for 'https://github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs.git/'
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs.git' into submodule path '/Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001/coq-projects/VST/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs' failed
Failed to clone 'coqdocjs' a second time, aborting
fatal: Failed to recurse into submodule path 'coq-projects/VST/coq-ext-lib'
```

is this suppose to happen? Why am I getting this request from git? Why can't it just pull the git repos and initialize the submodules as normal?

Comment: Are the github repositories for those submodules public? `https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs.git/` appears to be private or does not exist.

Comment: You might not have a choice here, but Git submodules kinda suck. You'll run into lots of little problems going down this path.

Comment: @Evert I don't have a choice :( I appreciate the hint. I discovered gitsubmodules sucked a while ago. Appreciate the advice -- wish I could take it. +1 for good advice.

Answer (score 1):

If one of those submodule repository (like [`coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs.git`](https://github.com/coq-ext-lib/coqdocjs.git)) is private, you would need to authenticate yourself for GitHub to check if you have the right to access those.

But since [Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/), you need to enter a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as a password, not your actual GitHub account password.

None of the repositories listed in [`UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/.gitmodules`](https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/blob/9b3bfed85eefecd68749650b1be5fef4c155c828/.gitmodules) are private, but maybe one of them includes itself a submodule repository reference which points to a private repository.

Try first `git submodule update --init --remote` (*without* the `--recursive`)

Comment: why without the `--recursive` flag?

Comment: very weird, in the server I am using it **is** pulling the git submodules but when I run it locally it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without recursive to avoid cloning potential private submodule of your declared submodules.

Comment: perhaps what I should be asking is "how to reset the git submodules state in my local computer". How do I do that? Then perhaps I can try to initialize the submodules correctly. I usually run `git submodule init` 1st followed by `git submodule update --init --remote` (but as this question reveals I am actually not entirely sure if that is correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342383/which-should-be-ran-first-git-submodule-update-or-git-submodule-init in general).

Comment: ok that was close! got `fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'coq_serapy'`

Comment: didn't work :( `(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ git submodule init
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ git submodule update --init --remote

fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'coq_serapy'`

Comment: That's seems a different issue. I'll have to check that in a few hours though. I will be off for a bit.

Comment: got it. Thanks for the help. Made a separate question to make it easier to track what is up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349905/how-does-one-fix-the-git-submodule-error-fatal-needed-a-single-revision-unable