# How does one fix the git submodule error fatal: Needed a single revision Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I keep getting this issue:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'coq_serapy'
```

I've tried

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

didn't work.

Removing the folder and running:

```
rm coq_serapy
# - git submodule init initializes your local configuration file to track the submodules your repository uses, it just sets up the configuration so that you can use the git submodule update command to clone and update the submodules.
git submodule init
# - The --remote option tells Git to update the submodule to the commit specified in the upstream repository, rather than the commit specified in the main repository. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988223/why-do-i-need-to-add-the-remote-to-gits-submodule-when-i-specify-the-branch?noredirect=1&lq=1
#git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
git submodule update --init --remote
```

didn't work. I've seen this [Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987847/unable-to-find-current-origin-master-revision-in-submodule-path) but didn't really help.

Any advice?

---

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ git submodule update --init --remote
Submodule 'coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10' (https://github.com/HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git) registered for path 'coq-projects/lin-alg'
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'coq_serapy'
```

Comment: What verrsion of Git are you using? Is it possible your version is trying to fetch `master` by default, while your remote submodule repositories have switch to `main` as the default branch, and no longer have `master`?