# How does one pin/freeze a version of the dependencies of an opam project/package and then install the project with such specified dependencies?

Tags: ocaml, coq, opam, dune

## How do we freeze an entire dependency tree/chain from an already working opam install?

I have a bunch of coq projects installed via opam right now. I'd like to figure out what commit they are using for their current install. I want to know this -- ideally **automatically** -- such that **the opam pkgs/projects and their dependencies are pinned/fixed/frozen** so that **future** opam installs/pins on the never break on them. For example if I knew the commit I could construct the opam switch need and install it with:

```
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
opam pin add coq-metalib https://github.com/plclub/metalib/commits/104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897
```

how do I do this? at the very least I'd like to be able to get commits like 104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897 from opam installs that are **already working**.

---

## How to automatically determine the git commit to make a permanent opam pin add url.git#commit install?

If I have a working set-up with opam. How do I get all the git commits for each opam project/package I have so to make the current install permanent? e.g. some projects it seems in coq get over written in the OPAM official repo so I want to lock those with git commits. So far manually checking them works:

```
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
opam pin add -y coq-metalib git+https://github.com/plclub/metalib.git#104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897
```

but I have a massive list of opam packages working right now and would like to make their install robust with the git commits. e.g. all these work **for now**:

```
# --- Install all Opam Dependencies: 1. create opam switch needed 2. then install all opam dependencies & projs
opam list
# - Create the 8.10.2 switch
opam switch create coq-8.10 4.07.1
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
opam pin add -y coq 8.10.2
# - Install dependency packages for 8.10
opam repo add coq-extra-dev https://coq.inria.fr/opam/extra-dev
# We don't need it in all opam switches due to incompatabilities: Run `opam repository add <coq-proj> --all-switches|--set-default' to use it in all existing switches, or in newly created switches, respectively. cmd: opam repository add coq-extra-dev --all-switches
opam repo add coq-released https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released
opam repo add psl-opam-repository https://github.com/uds-psl/psl-opam-repository.git
opam install -y coq-serapi
opam install -y coq-struct-tact
opam install -y coq-inf-seq-ext

opam install -y coq-smpl
opam install -y coq-int-map
opam install -y coq-pocklington
opam install -y coq-mathcomp-ssreflect coq-mathcomp-bigenough coq-mathcomp-algebra
opam install -y coq-fcsl-pcm
opam install -y coq-list-string
opam install -y coq-error-handlers
opam install -y coq-function-ninjas
opam install -y coq-algebra
opam install -y coq-zorns-lemma
opam pin -y add menhir 20190626
# coq-equations seems to rely on ocamlfind for it's build, but doesn't
# list it as a dependency, so opam sometimes tries to install
# coq-equations before ocamlfind. Splitting this into a separate
# install call prevents that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75452026/how-do-i-install-ocamlfind-first-properly-before-other-opam-packages-without-roo, untested for now
opam install -y ocamlfind
opam install -y coq-equations coq-metacoq coq-metacoq-checker coq-metacoq-template

# lin-alg-8.10 needs opam switch coq-8.10
git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10 git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git coq-projects/lin-alg
git submodule update --init coq-projects/lin-alg
(cd coq-projects/lin-alg && make "$@" && make install)
# to confirm it installed look for lin-alg: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/81, for now you can confirm by trying to install it again and it all looks alright
#opam list
#opam list | grep lin-alg-8.10

# Install the psl base-library from source
mkdir -p deps
git clone -b coq-8.10 git@github.com:uds-psl/base-library.git deps/base-library
(cd deps/base-library && make "$@" && make install)
git clone git@github.com:davidnowak/bellantonicook.git deps/bellantonicook
(cd deps/bellantonicook && make "$@" && make install)
opam list | grep base-library

# -- Get cheerios, req to have old versions work in opam: https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios/issues/17
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
# opam install might give issues since it gets the most recent version from the official OPAM repository
#opam -y install coq-cheerios
#opam install -y coq-verdi
# use opam pin since pin is created to install specific version (e.g. from git, local, etc.)
opam pin add coq-cheerios git+https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios.git#9c7f66e57b91f706d70afa8ed99d64ed98ab367
#opam pin add coq-cheerios https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios.git\#9c7f66e57b91f706d70afa8ed99d64ed98ab367d
#opam pin add coq-verdi https://github.com/uwplse/verdi/tree/f3ef8d77afcac495c0864de119e83b25d294e8bb
opam pin add coq-verdi git+https://github.com/uwplse/verdi.git#f3ef8d77afcac495c0864de119e83b25d294e8bb
# use opam pin since pin is created to install specific version (e.g. from git, local, etc.)
```

---

## Context: installing proverbot9001 coq-projects dependencies that have their OPAM repo code overwritten by original authors

I have this issue were I try to install an opam package (coq project/pkg in my specific case) that I have downloaded/cloned via a git submodule and when I do try to opam install it it fails. It fails, although I have cloned the right version of the coq project/pkg. The source of failure is something I've been told [here](https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/78#issuecomment-1419685112) because it is imho very hard to infer/deduce that from the error message:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ opam install -y coq-cheerios

[ERROR] Package conflict!
  * Missing dependency:
    - coq >= 8.14
    not available because the package is pinned to version 8.10.2

No solution found, exiting
```

it says a newer version of coq is needed but it's very confusing why that is the case. In python there is a `setup.py` or a `requirements.txt` file that makes all of this a little bit more clear (dependency management is always a pain afaik :( ).

I am wondering, is there such a file in opam where I can specify for the coq-projects I am using which version of the dependencies I need so I don't have to go back and fix everything? e.g. [in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33468993/1601580) I'd do:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt  # Python3
pip freeze > requirements.txt  # Python2
```

can I do this in ocaml? Ideally automatically. Even more ideally looping through all the coq-projs in my current repo under the folder `coq-projects/` and create such a freeze of the dependencies for future installs? Once that is there how would I install the downloaded/cloned coq proj with the specified forzen dependencies?

---

## Why can't we just extract the deps from a list like pip does? It's linear once a working installation is set up

I don't understand something about opam vs pip. Once a working installation is set up -- it's not a chain or recursive structure of installations. It's simply a list of installations that can be frozen with pip. Is that not possible with opam? If not why not and why is it so hard to fix?

---

## Useful links

related discussion to solve this issue:

- trying to get coq-cheerios & verdi to work by getting the right commits for them: https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios/issues/17 , trying to get support for cheerios for coq 8.10: https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios/issues/12
- this is a related question I asked when I thought it was my cloning of the coq-projects I was going to build [How does one git submodule add a specific commit and have it be recorded in the .modules files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75417355/how-does-one-git-submodule-add-a-specific-commit-and-have-it-be-recorded-in-the) but before I even build them I need to get their dependencies installed! e.g. via opam. Some proverbot installed from source :( and Idk how to fix those yet e.g. metalib: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/82
- I might have an issue with coq-serapi too: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/78
- when I thought creating my own forks would work https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/83 but likely just getting the opam install/pin to work with the commit is better e.g. `opam pin add coq-metalib https://github.com/plclub/metalib/commits/104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897`.
- cross at ocaml discuss: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/how-does-one-pin-freeze-a-version-of-the-dependencies-of-an-opam-project-package-and-then-install-the-project-with-such-specified-dependencies/11424
- another discussion when running a giant set of opam installs: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/55
- related & likely culprit of issues; is it true that OPAM allows none addative updates to their official repository of packages? https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/is-it-true-that-the-official-opam-repository-allows-non-additive-updates-to-the-projects-packages-pushed-to-it/11432

Comment: I don't understand something about opam vs pip. Once a working installation is set up -- it's not a chain or recursive structure of installations. It's simply a list of installations that can be frozen with pip. Is that not possible with opam? If not why not and why is it so hard to fix?

Comment: Also asked here https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/how-does-one-pin-freeze-a-version-of-the-dependencies-of-an-opam-project-package-and-then-install-the-project-with-such-specified-dependencies/11424

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the problem here is that the Cheerios project **used to be** compatible with older versions of Coq, and other projects depend on that. In another package manager, you could just pin to the older version of Cheerios and everything that used that version would be fine. But in Opam there's no guarantee that having a working dependency chain at one time means there will always be a working dependency chain.

EDIT: I don't think `opam lock` would work here unless it's tarring up the packages or something, because opam is no longer aware of a version  of Cheerios which is compatible with Coq 8.10. That version of Cheerios has been erased from the opam repositories, replaced with a newer version which is no longer compatible.

Comment: I don't understand something about opam vs pip. Once a working installation is set up -- it's not a chain or recursive structure of installations. It's simply a list of installations that can be frozen with pip. Is that not possible with opam? If not why not and why is it so hard to fix?

Comment: can't you share your built env with `opam lock`? from a quick skim it might be useful if you have a working env already `opam-lock - Create locked opam files to share build environments across hosts.` more permanent link: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/84

Comment: sorry I'm puzzled, why doesn't `opam lock` work?

Comment: Alex, can you confirm to me how we know that cheerios is indeed overwriting old version of their opam source uploaded to the official opam repository?

Answer (score 0):

The `cheerios` coq project that you are building states explicitly that it is only compatible with Coq 8.14 and later in its `README.md`. I am not sure which part is confusing?

More generally, you can specify which versions of packages your project is compatible with in the dependency fields of your opam file.

If you need to freeze a dependency tree, you can also lock an opam package to depends on the installed versions of its dependencies with `opam lock`.

Comment: `coq-cheerios` authors had a version compatible with 8.10. I need exactly that version and since they overwrote the opam version on the internet it's giving me issues. I was told to find the commit that supports 8.10 and install it via `opam pin add coq-metalib https://github.com/plclub/metalib/commits/104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897` or similar command.

Comment: can you explain your final paragraph a bit more? `If you need to freeze a dependency tree, you can also lock an opam package to depends on the installed versions of its dependencies with opam lock.` how can I use that to do the original question?

Comment: Once you have pinned versions of your dependencies that work, you can use `opam lock` to freeze those versions in a opam lock file that record the exact versions of the dependencies including your non-local pinned dependencies.

Comment: would this make the installations reproducible even if the version upstream (in the official OPAM repository) get overwritten as is the case with `coq-cheerios`, `verdi`, and `coq-metalib`?

Comment: (I am  surprised that the coq opam repository allow non-additive updates to the repository. Typically, this is against the policy of the OCaml opam repository which at most updates the metadata of a package. )If you pinned remote version of the packages with an explicit commit, the installation should be reproducible as long as the remote source remains available.

Comment: I'm not an opam expert but I will try to find evidence if this is really true, two preliminary questions I asked here https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/is-it-true-that-the-official-opam-repository-allows-non-additive-updates-to-the-projects-packages-pushed-to-it/11432 and here https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios/issues/19 later is cheerios which seems to give me the issue

Comment: For readers, the previous affirmation is false: the coq opam repository do not overwrite package. However, the coq extra-development repository as explained by the name do only contain development package which, as advertised, don't have a stable version yet released.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to install everything by documenting the reversion since the first try. Different way to install has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75513771/1601580

since it's bad practice to give only links I will give the sample script that shows the different ways to install with version that that answer gives:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# -- Install Opam : Opam is for managing OCaml compiler(s), tools, and libraries. But it can be used for related things e.g. Coq Theorem Prover.
source $HOME/proverbot9001/install_opam.sh

# -- install Ruby, as that is for some reason required to build the "system" project
if command -v ruby &>/dev/null; then
  echo "Ruby is installed and its version is $(ruby -v)."
else
  echo "Ruby is not installed, going to install it..."
  source $HOME/proverbot9001/install_ruby_snap.sh
fi
ruby -v


# -- Git submodule "pull" all submodules (and init it)
# - git submodule init initializes your local configuration file to track the submodules your repository uses, it just sets up the configuration so that you can use the git submodule update command to clone and update the submodules.
git submodule init
# -- only need git submodule update --init because we don't want to fetch from remote to not break proverbot9001 & there are no recursive submodules
#git submodule update --init --recursive --remote  # not needed, no git repo has other submodules so --recursive not needed, --remote not needed because it might update the coq proj and make it incompatible with the coq version we use
#git submodule update --init --remote  # not needed, --remote not needed because it might update the coq proj and make it incompatible with the coq version we use
git submodule update --init
# - for each submodule pull from the right branch according to .gitmodule file. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988223/why-do-i-need-to-add-the-remote-to-gits-submodule-when-i-specify-the-branch?noredirect=1&lq=1
#git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git switch $(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch || echo master || echo main )'
# - check it's in specified branch. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998463/why-does-git-submodule-status-not-match-the-output-of-git-branch-of-my-submodule
git submodule status


# --- Install all Opam Dependencies: 1. create opam switch needed 2. then install all opam dependencies & projs
#opam list
# - Create the 8.10.2 switch
opam switch create coq-8.10 4.07.1
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
opam pin add -y coq 8.10.2
# - Install dependency packages for 8.10
opam repo add coq-extra-dev https://coq.inria.fr/opam/extra-dev
# We don't need it in all opam switches due to incompatabilities: Run `opam repository add <coq-proj> --all-switches|--set-default' to use it in all existing switches, or in newly created switches, respectively. cmd: opam repository add coq-extra-dev --all-switches
opam repo add coq-released https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released
opam repo add psl-opam-repository https://github.com/uds-psl/psl-opam-repository.git


# - opam installs coq 8.10
# this opam package is properly mantained so opam install is fine, no need for opam pin with url+git commit. ref: https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-serapi/issues/320
opam install -y coq-serapi
# above works but bellow makes explicit the version
#opam install -y coq-serapi=8.10.0+0.7.2

opam install -y coq-struct-tact
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
#opam pin add -y coq-struct-tact git+https://github.com/uwplse/StructTact.git#b95f041cb83986fb0fe1f9689d7196e2f09a4839

opam install -y coq-inf-seq-ext
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow seems to work but some warning appear
opam pin add -y coq-inf-seq-ext git+https://github.com/DistributedComponents/InfSeqExt.git#19f6359e65ecb872d49208f60bf8951fb76fe091

opam install -y coq-smpl
# above works, bellow makes explicit the version
#opam install -y coq-smpl=8.10
#opam install -y coq-smpl=8.10.2

opam install -y coq-int-map
# above works, bellow makes explicit the version
#opam install -y coq-int-map=8.10.0

opam install -y coq-pocklington
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
opam install -y coq-pocklington=8.10.0
#opam pin add -y coq-pocklington git+https://github.com/coq-community/pocklington.git#1940ddd40622772e1d81a31320431799a437c512

opam install -y coq-mathcomp-ssreflect
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
opam install -y coq-mathcomp-ssreflect=1.11.0

opam install -y coq-mathcomp-bigenough
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
#opam install -y coq-mathcomp-bigenough=1.0.1

opam install -y coq-mathcomp-algebra
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
#opam install -y coq-mathcomp-algebra=1.11.0

opam install -y coq-fcsl-pcm
opam install -y coq-fcsl-pcm=1.2.0

opam install -y coq-list-string
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
#opam install -y coq-list-string=2.1.2

opam install -y coq-error-handlers
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
#opam install -y coq-error-handlers=1.2.0

opam install -y coq-function-ninjas
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
opam install -y coq-function-ninjas=1.0.0

opam install -y coq-algebra
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
#opam install -y coq-algebra=8.10.0

opam install -y coq-zorns-lemma
# dev seems to work but providing the bottom just in case, bellow works
opam install -y coq-zorns-lemma=8.10.0

opam pin -y add menhir 20190626
# coq-equations seems to rely on ocamlfind for it's build, but doesn't
# list it as a dependency, so opam sometimes tries to install
# coq-equations before ocamlfind. Splitting this into a separate
# install call prevents that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75452026/how-do-i-install-ocamlfind-first-properly-before-other-opam-packages-without-roo, untested for now
opam install -y ocamlfind=1.9.1

opam install -y coq-equations
# bellow seems to work too
#opam install -y coq-equations=1.2.1+8.10

opam install -y coq-metacoq
# below seems to work too
#opam install -y coq-metacoq=1.0~alpha2+8.10

opam install -y coq-metacoq-checker
# below seems to work too
#opam install -y coq-metacoq-checker=1.0~alpha2+8.10

opam install -y coq-metacoq-template
# below seems to work too
#opam install -y coq-metacoq-template=1.0~alpha2+8.10

# lin-alg-8.10 needs opam switch coq-8.10
git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10 git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git coq-projects/lin-alg
git submodule update --init coq-projects/lin-alg
(cd coq-projects/lin-alg && make "$@" && make install)
#(cd coq-projects/lin-alg && opam install -y .)  # no make file it seems
# to confirm it installed look for lin-alg: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/81, for now you can confirm by trying to install it again and it all looks alright
#opam list
#opam list | grep lin-alg-8.10

# Install the psl base-library from source
mkdir -p deps
git clone -b coq-8.10 git@github.com:uds-psl/base-library.git deps/base-library
(cd deps/base-library && make "$@" && make install)
git clone git@github.com:davidnowak/bellantonicook.git deps/bellantonicook
(cd deps/bellantonicook && make "$@" && make install)
opam list | grep base-library

# -- Get cheerios, req to have old versions work in opam: https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios/issues/17, https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/92
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
# opam install might give issues since it gets the most recent version from the official OPAM repository, opam devs can overwrite what they push to the OPAM repo, thus: use opam pin since pin is created to install specific version (e.g. from git, local, etc.)
# - cheerios
# suggested by alex https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios/commits/f0c7659c44999c6cfcd484dc3182affc3ff4248a for 8.10 but mine seems fine
#opam pin add coq-cheerios git+https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios.git#f0c7659c44999c6cfcd484dc3182affc3ff4248a
# my cheerios installs/pins
opam pin add coq-cheerios git+https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios.git#9c7f66e57b91f706d70afa8ed99d64ed98ab367

# - verdi
# bellow suggested by alex https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/93 likey for 8.10, but mine seems fine
# opam pin add coq-verdi git+https://github.com/uwplse/verdi.git#064cc4fb2347453bf695776ed820ffb5fbc1d804
# my verdi installs/pins
#opam pin add coq-verdi https://github.com/uwplse/verdi/tree/f3ef8d77afcac495c0864de119e83b25d294e8bb
opam pin add coq-verdi git+https://github.com/uwplse/verdi.git#f3ef8d77afcac495c0864de119e83b25d294e8bb

# -- Get metalib for coq-8.10 via commit when getting it through git submodules (unsure if needed)
# - use the one with commit even if it doesn't work just to document the commit explicitly in the .modules file
git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/metalib https://github.com/plclub/metalib.git coq-projects/metalib
#git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/metalib https://github.com/plclub/metalib.git#104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897 coq-projects/metalib
git submodule update --init coq-projects/metalib
(cd coq-projects/metalib && git checkout 104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897 && git rev-parse HEAD)
(cd coq-projects/metalib && opam install -y .)

# bellow likely not needed: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/86
# install it again since I think his code has pointers to a version under deps, could unify with above but it's less work to just accept as is and install it, ref: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/77
# - use the one with commit even if it doesn't work just to document the commit explicitly in the .modules file
git submodule add -f --name deps/metalib https://github.com/plclub/metalib.git deps/metalib
#git submodule add -f --name deps/metalib https://github.com/plclub/metalib.git#104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897 deps/metalib
git submodule update --init deps/metalib
(cd deps/metalib && git checkout 104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897)
(git rev-parse HEAD && cd ..)
(cd deps/metalib && opam install -y .)

# - Install metalib for coq-8.10 via opam pin (it seems to overwrite the isntalled versions so let's have opam pin be the last one?)
opam pin add -y coq-metalib git+https://github.com/plclub/metalib.git#104fd9efbfd048b7df25dbac7b971f41e8e67897

# -- Get deps opam packages/projects for coq-8.12
# Create the coq 8.12 switch
opam switch create coq-8.12 4.07.1
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.12 --set-switch)
opam pin add -y coq 8.12.2

# Install the packages that can be installed directly through opam
opam repo add coq-released https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released
opam repo add coq-extra-dev https://coq.inria.fr/opam/extra-dev

# - opam installs
# this opam package is properly mantained so opam install is fine, no need for opam pin with url+git commit. ref: https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-serapi/issues/320
opam install -y coq-serapi

opam install -y coq-smp
# run bellow in case above break when using the intended coq switch
#opam install -y coq-smpl=8.12

opam install -y coq-metacoq-template
# run bellow in case above break when using the intended coq switch
#opam install -y coq-metacoq-template=1.0~beta1+8.12

opam install -y coq-metacoq-checker
# run bellow in case above break when using the intended coq switch
#opam install -y coq-metacoq-checker=1.0~beta1+8.12

opam install -y coq-equations
# run bellow in case above break when using the intended coq switch
#opam install -y coq-equations=1.2.3+8.12

opam install -y coq-mathcomp-ssreflect
# run bellow in case above break when using the intended coq switch
#opam install -y coq-mathcomp-ssreflect=1.14.0

opam install -y coq-mathcomp-algebra
# run bellow in case above break when using the intended coq switch
opam install -y coq-mathcomp-algebra=1.14.0

opam install -y coq-mathcomp-field
# run bellow in case above break when using the intended coq switch
#opam install -y coq-mathcomp-field=1.14.0

opam install -y menhir
# ref for commit compatible in a stable way with coq 8.12 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465305/what-is-the-tag-for-menhir-for-coq-8-12-when-installing-it-with-opam-install-y
#opam pin add -y menhir 20190626
# 20190626 likely more stable than dev but if dev works I suppose it's more up to date and better
#opam install -y menhir=dev

# advice of coq-ext-lib version that might be better than bellow ref: https://github.com/coq-community/coq-ext-lib/issues/132
opam install -y coq-ext-lib
#opam install -y coq-ext-lib=dev  # dev versions always make me unease
#opam install -y coq-ext-lib=0.11.7  # this seemed to work but it says it downgraded, for now leave as is

# advice of coq-ext-lib version that might be better than bellow ref: https://github.com/Lysxia/coq-simple-io/issues/60
opam install -y coq-simple-io
#opam install -y coq-simple-io=dev  # dev versions always make me unease
#opam install -y coq-simple-io=1.5.0  # this seemed to work but it says it downgraded, for now leave as is

# - Install some coqgym deps that don't have the right versions in their official opam packages
# The head commit at this time worked, so I am leaving it hardcoded after this install. If bellow fails use the hardcoded commit one. Details, ref: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/90
git clone git@github.com:uwplse/StructTact.git deps/StructTact
(cd deps/StructTact && opam install -y .)
# above worked, but leaving code bellow in case it's needed
#git clone git@github.com:uwplse/StructTact.git deps/StructTact
#(cd deps/StructTact && git checkout f8d4f8a0e04df0522a839462e725a48d54145b48 && git rev-parse HEAD)
#(cd deps/StructTact && opam install -y .)
# if above fails perhaps this will work? most recent commit at this time 2f2ff253be29bb09f36cab96d036419b18a95b00, ref: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/90
#git clone git@github.com:uwplse/StructTact.git deps/StructTact
#(cd deps/StructTact && git checkout 2f2ff253be29bb09f36cab96d036419b18a95b00 && git rev-parse HEAD)
#(cd deps/StructTact && opam install -y .)

# Some packages that don't have an official opam repository version don't need commit hashes?
git clone git@github.com:DistributedComponents/InfSeqExt.git deps/InfSeqExt
(cd deps/InfSeqExt && opam install -y .)
# above worked but bellow might have not, but leaving code bellow in case it's needed ref: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/91
#git clone git@github.com:DistributedComponents/InfSeqExt.git deps/InfSeqExt
#(cd deps/InfSeqExt && git checkout 91b2d9bdc580c7ccb5bf2f50fffb6ebabab2715c && git rev-parse HEAD)
#(cd deps/InfSeqExt && opam install -y .)

# Cheerios has its own issues, this seems to have worked since cheerios-runtime is present, check later: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/92
git clone git@github.com:uwplse/cheerios.git deps/cheerios
(cd deps/cheerios && opam install -y --ignore-constraints-on=coq .)
## this doesn't seem to do anything different than the above attempt, above uses dev & ends up using cheerios-runtime
#git clone git@github.com:uwplse/cheerios.git deps/cheerios
##(cd deps/cheerios && git checkout 9c7f66e57b91f706d70afa8ed99d64ed98ab367d && git rev-parse HEAD)
#(cd deps/cheerios && git checkout 37a30160b4e232555245fbbfb64acfc3d03fda91 && git rev-parse HEAD)  # right before coq >=8.14 warning
##(cd deps/cheerios && git checkout 81a8f820e639067fda0082493a18c7a9b30ee69d && git rev-parse HEAD)  # coq >=8.14 warning
##(cd deps/cheerios && opam install -y .)
#(cd deps/cheerios && opam install -y --ignore-constraints-on=coq .)

# Verdi has its own issues, this doesn't seem to have worked no verdi-runtime, check later: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/93
git clone git@github.com:uwplse/verdi.git deps/verdi
(cd coq-projects/verdi && opam install -y --ignore-constraints-on=coq .)
# this doesn't seem to do anything different than the above attempt, above uses dev & ends up using verdi-runtime
#git clone git@github.com:uwplse/verdi.git deps/verdi
#(cd deps/verdi && git checkout fdb4ede19d2150c254f0ebcfbed4fb9547a734b0 && git rev-parse HEAD)
#(cd deps/verdi && git checkout 3d22ce073f7d16da58eb8e1aa3c71bf8f588a04f && git rev-parse HEAD)
#(cd deps/verdi && git checkout 35508f2af94f9da979ece0cbdfa191019f2c5478 && git rev-parse HEAD) # right before coq >=8.14 warning
#(cd deps/verdi && git checkout cb016cf9d2ae61ff757a0b6fa443b391a5416b63 && git rev-parse HEAD)  # coq >=8.14 warning
# seperate commit suggested by https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/93 idk if its for 8.12 but I assume not due to original authors saying they don't support 8.12 and Alex saying proverbot doesn't need 8.12 for cheerios
#(cd deps/verdi && git checkout 064cc4fb2347453bf695776ed820ffb5fbc1d804 && git rev-parse HEAD)  # coq >=8.14 warning
#(cd deps/verdi && opam install -y .)

# Install fcsl-pcm
git clone git@github.com:imdea-software/fcsl-pcm.git coq-projects/fcsl-pcm
(cd coq-projects/fcsl-pcm && git checkout fab4dfe3ca58ecf8aefeb8fa4ac4a2659b231f24 && git rev-parse HEAD)
(cd coq-projects/fcsl-pcm && opam install -y .)
#(cd coq-projects/fcsl-pcm && make "$@" && make install)

# Finally, sync the opam state back to global https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/52
# NOT NEEDED rsync -av --delete /tmp/${USER}_dot_opam/ $HOME/.opam.dir | tqdm --desc="Writing shared opam state" > /dev/null
```